# How can I find first list of childrens with the same class from multiple levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a small thing I hang up on.
I have this markup

```
<div class="menu-build-group"> <!-- Level 1 -->
<ul class="menu-build-items">
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">Level 1 Level 1 Level 1
        <div class="menu-item-relative-wrap">
            <div class="menu-build-item">
                <div class="menu-item-handle">
                    <span class="menu-item-number">1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-keypress">
            <div class="menu-build-group">
                <ul class="menu-build-items">
                    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">Level 2 Level 2 Level 2
                        <div class="menu-item-relative-wrap">
                            <div class="menu-build-item">
                                <div class="menu-item-handle">
                                    <span class="menu-item-number">1.1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">...</li>
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">...</li>
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">...</li>
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">...</li>
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the menu-item-number just for the first level.

I used this code witch I know is not working in my case.

```
    function changeSectionNumbers(triggerEl){

        var sectionMenuGr = triggerEl.closest('.menu-build-group');

        sectionMenuGr.find('.menu-build-item-wrapper').each(function(index){
            var myIndex = index+1;
            $(this).find('.menu-item-number').text(myIndex); 
        })
   }
```

Is there any way I can get only the first level of elements "menu-build-item-wrapper" and change the menu-item-number text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul class="root-list menu-build-items">
    <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">Level 1 Level 1 Level 1
       <div class="menu-keypress">
          <div class="menu-build-group">
             <ul class="menu-build-items">
                 <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">Level 2 Level 2 Level 2
```

Please note the `root-list` class added to the first `ul` element

```
$("ul.root-list > li.menu-build-item-wrapper").each(function(index){
    var myIndex = index+1;
    $(this).find('.menu-item-number').text(myIndex); 
});
```

Comment: I need to target the .menu-build-group since there are multiple triggers  some of witch are childs of  .menu-build-group and some are inside the UL.

Also i use that function to change the menu-item-number in the Second level as well;.

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap the outer most ul in a div eg

```
<div class="allitems">...</div>
```

Then you can use the the direct descendant operator:  `>`

```
$(".allitems > 
 .menu-build-items > 
 .menu-build-item-wrapper > 
 .menu-item-relative-wrap > 
 .menu-build-item > 
 .menu-item-handle > 
 span");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the first level item by using below selector

```
$(".menu-build-group .menu-build-item-wrapper .menu-item-number:eq(0)")
```

Below loop to change text.

```
 var count=1;
 $(".menu-build-group .menu-build-item-wrapper .menu-item-number:eq(0)").
   each( function( ) { 
    this.innerHTML=count;count++;
   });
```

Comment: Each of the <li class="menu-build-item-wrapper">...</li> has the same content as the first one.

I want to change the number in first level of <li> like 1,2,3,4,5 etc

Comment: @AnghelGabriel hi then use counter something like below. var count=1;$(".menu-build-group .menu-build-item-wrapper .menu-item-number:eq(0)").each( function(  ) {
  this.innerHTML=count;count++;
});. Still you need correction , better give output sample.By that easily fixed up. THANKS.